# In Visual Studio 2019, how can I design a Panel in the same way as Form?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

For some reasons, I want to define `Panel` (Windows Form) using `Visual Studio Designer` support.

When I define a `Form` or a `UserControl`, I get a rectangle in which I can put some controls manually to design my Form or my UserControl.

Example of `Panel` (currently it is a `UserContr`ol) that I want to create

[image]

But I don't find any solution to define a control derivated from `Panel` !

I tried to use `Component` but it is impossible to drag and drop controls from Toolbox.

I tried `UserControl` followed by replacement of `UserControl` name by `Pane`l but after this replacement, manual design stop working all all controls previously added in UserControl are now display as a list of controls.

Exemple of what I gat when renaming 'UserControl' to 'Panel'

[image]

How can I do ?

Is it possible ? Using special attributes ?

There exists a similar question for Visual Studio 2010 posted in 2012 !

[design panel without parent form in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870294/design-panel-without-parent-form-in-visual-studio)

Comment: [Walkthrough: Create a control that takes advantage of design-time features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/creating-a-wf-control-design-time-features?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: See also; [IToolboxUser Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.itoolboxuser)

Comment: There is [*some* support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2863807/17034) for enabling design mode for a user control, but that's not practical here.  No, once you created a component, you have to use it as-is.

Comment: ok, in resume, it is impossible using Visual Studio 2019 ! Thanks for your help

Comment: Now, when I will add this control to a specific Panel named XPanel, I first add XPanel in a Container and then I can add my UserControl in XPanel. It is a little more complicated but  that is the only solution that I have found.